# How to create process with Boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I have to C++ projects and I need to join them in on module. When I ask Google "How to create process with Boost?" it gives me only Boost.process. But this library as I understood doesn't support a long time and I tired but when I include this library in gives errors in it with Boost 1_54.
I also saw boost.thread but examples that I saw create threads from functions but not process on other projects.
What I can do with it?

Comment: Do you mean to `fork()`?

Comment: Besides the mentioned Boost Process library, you have to use the operating systems native calls to create new processes.

Comment: I know not so much about it... Fork() will be work indentically under Windows, Linux, Ubunta? I need it to be cross-platform.